# Run filter queries in Appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to run the query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='foo' AND passwd='bar'
```

This always returns None.My table has entries matching the query.
I feel it has to do something with indexing.I edited my index.yaml to

```
indexes:

- kind: users
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: uname
    direction: asc
  - name: passwd
    direction: asc
```

But when I define `uname=db.TextProperty(required=True,indexed=True)`,it returns a strange error saying

```
<class 'google.appengine.ext.db.ConfigurationError'>: indexed must be False. 
      args = ('indexed must be False.',) 
      message = 'indexed must be False.'
```

I call it strange because when i google the error,there are zero exact matches.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to run the query in the Datastore viewer of the admin console. It suggests you what indexed to create.

However, text properties are not indexable. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#TextProperty)

> Unlike StringProperty, a TextProperty value can be more than 500 characters long. However, TextProperty values are not indexed and cannot be used in filters or sort orders.